# Win32_Printer ManagementObjectSearcher Error (VS2008 C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, object

First, this code worked in VS2005.

The code in VS2008 crashes with an UnauthorizedAccessException whenever I try stepping over the foreach loop and assign a ManagementObject.

```
public static List<string> GetPrintersCollection() {
  if (printers == null) {
    printers = new List<string>();
    string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer";
    try {
      using (ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrinters = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery)) {
        ManagementObjectCollection Printers = searchPrinters.Get(); // <= Printers data below
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in Printers) { // <= Error Here
          printers.Add(printer.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
        }
      }
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException err) {
      Console.WriteLine(err.Message); // the message is an empty string
      throw new Exception("PrinterSpool - GetPrintersCollection: You do not have authorization to access this printer.");
    } catch (Exception err) {
      throw new Exception(string.Format("PrinterSpool - GetPrintersCollection: {0}", err.Message));
    }
  }
  return printers;
}
```

StackTrace =
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at AcpClasses.PrinterSpool.GetPrintersCollection()...

When I try to view the data in the Locals window, these fields look immediately suspect:
1. Count - Value: "Function evaluation timed out."
2. IsSynchronized - Value: Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out.
3. SyncRoot - Value: Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out.

How can I try to debug this further to find out what is going on?

Comment: Comment:  
Defined elsewhere is List<string> printers = null;  
This code also no longer works in Visual Studio 2005 (I just checked with a Console Application that queries the Win32_Printer only).

Comment: I've added some code in my answer that should help in diagnosing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug further you need to inspect `Printers` before entering the foreach loop.

1. Put a breakpoint on the
   `searchPrinters.Get()` line.
2. Press F10
3. Now inspect your item.

Another thing that should help is changing `err.Message` to `err.ToString()`.

For what it's worth, I debugged this with no problems running both VS 2005 & 2008 on XP.

**EDIT**:  Posting code for you to try.

```
public static List<string> GetPrintersCollection()
{
    if (printers == null)
    {
        printers = new List<string>();
        string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer";
        try
        {
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrinters = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection Printers = searchPrinters.Get(); // <= Printers data below
                foreach (ManagementObject printer in Printers)
                {
                    printers.Add(printer.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException err)
        {
            //Log & re-throw
            Console.WriteLine("Caught UnauthorizedAccessException:  " + err.ToString()); 
            throw;  //re-throw existing exception, not a new one
        }
        //there's no reason to catch the plain-old Exception 
    }

    return printers;
}
```

**EDIT**:  The only other thing I can think of is to manually go through your *Printers and Faxes* to see if any are causing problems for you.

Comment: -  Printers {System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection} System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection
'+' Count 
'Printers.Count' threw an exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'

Comment: Meanwhile, the err.ToString() gave this data:  
"PrinterSpool - GetPrintersCollection: You do not have authorization to access this printer.\r\nSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException\r\n   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)\r\n   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at win32_printer.Program.GetPrintersCollection()

Comment: Does the information above help any? I don't know what to do with it. Obviously, I am an admin on my own machine, but I also want this application to work for others (i.e. non-admins) on other machines.

*** (NOTE: Sorry for posting this reply in multiple comments, but SO seems to impose a limit on the comment length, and I don't know how to otherwise respond to a message.) ***

Comment: I've posted some code for you to try.  From your second comment, you were posting the content of *your* exception handling which I believe is partially preventing you from solving your problem.

Comment: Same error Mr. Salonen:   ***"Caught UnauthorizedAccessException:  System.UnauthorizedAccessException\r\n   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)\r\n   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at win32_printer.Program.GetPrintersCollection2() in C:\\Shared\\jp2Testing\\win32_printer\\Program.cs:line 57"***

Comment: In WinXP, under "Printers and Faxes", I can open all printers listed  and print a test page without a problem. Under Users, I am listed as an Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       `string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer";

        ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery(strQuery);

        ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);
        query.Options.Timeout=new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = query.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in queryCollection)
            {....}`
```

The default value for Timeout must be TimeSpan.MaxValue, but...

It was a solution in my case.